# time synchronization

Tags: ros, imu, rosbag, ros-kinetic, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I write the following launch code in order to record synchronized data from 4 topics (color image, depth image, joy command, and IMU)

```
<launch>
    <arg name="approx_sync" default="true"/>

<!-- Putting the time back to real time-->
    <rosparam>
       /use_sim_time : false
    </rosparam>

  <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record_Test" output="screen" 
    args="record -o record_Test /camera/depth/image_raw /camera/rgb/image_raw /joy /mobile_base/sensors/imu_data_raw"/>
    <param name="approx_sync" type="bool" value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>

</launch>
```

I use ApproximateTime Synchronizer but it does not work! still, I got a bag file with a different number of messages from each topic.

what I doing wrong?!

any help appriciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288007/time-synchronization/) by [khadija](https://answers.ros.org/users/34050/khadija/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosbag` does not do any time syncronising as far as I know. The `approx_sync` parameter is not a parameter the `record` node accepts/uses.

Can you tell us where you found that parameter used in conjunction with the `record` node?

---

Edit:

> I just thought that I can use it with record .. so what is your advice, how can I get a syncronized data??

I think 'best practice' would still be to use [message_filters/ApproximateTime Policy](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy) for this in a custom node.

It would be a nice addition to rosbag though to be able to do this. Perhaps 'someone' has already done this or written a custom `record` node that support this out-of-the-box?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khadija](https://answers.ros.org/users/34050/khadija/) on 2018-04-09**:
I just thought that I can use it with record .. so what is your advice, how can I get a syncronized data??

**Comment by [khadija](https://answers.ros.org/users/34050/khadija/) on 2018-04-09**:
so how should I merge my launch file with that python code? could you help me?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-09**:\

> how should I merge my launch file with that python code?

You can't, that's not how this works.

I would suggest to see whether someone else has already done something like this, and if not, write a node that uses `message_filters` to do a synchronised recording.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-09**:
But also note that you might not even need to do a synchronised recording: if you're just looking for a way to process synchronised pairs/triples/etc of messages, then perhaps just recording with `rosbag` and *then* using `message_filters` would work just as well.

**Comment by [khadija](https://answers.ros.org/users/34050/khadija/) on 2018-04-09**:
do you mean that after I record my data then I can bring my bag file to that python code to do a time synchronizer ??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-09**:
You can record your bag, write the synchroniser node, then play the bag and have the node synchronise live, yes.

**Comment by [khadija](https://answers.ros.org/users/34050/khadija/) on 2018-04-09**:
Thank you for your time. I will do a search on how can I do that, and if you find anyone did what I'm trying to do; please link it to me.